# Refactoring : Would like a single function/event handler to do the same thing

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I am new to programming and JS as can be seen in my code. The background colour and text on the page changes according to which target `<li>` tag is clicked, possibly i.e. function, objects, arrays or if statements using `eventListeners` and events handlers.

I am looking for inspiration here so that I can finally understand how programming really works.

See my code below.

```js
let navLink1 = document.querySelector('color1');
let navLink2 = document.querySelector('color2');
let navLink3 = document.querySelector('color3');
let navLink4 = document.querySelector('color4');

let p1 = document.querySelector('para');

navLink1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.body.style.background = "color1";
    document.innerHTML(p1) = "New text!";  
});

navLink2.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.body.style.background = "color2";
    document.innerHTML(p1) = "New text!";  
});

navLink3.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.body.style.background = "color3";
    document.innerHTML(p1) = "New text!";
});

navLink4.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.body.style.background = "color4";
    document.innerHTML(p1) = "New text!";
});
```

```html
<ul class ='nav'>
   <li class ='color1'><a href=''>color1</a></li>
   <li class ='color2'><a href=''>color2</a></li>
   <li class ='color3'><a href=''>color3</a></li>
   <li class ='color4'><a href=''>color4</a></li>
</ul>

<h2>The text in the <p> tag below changes according to clicked link in the menu</h2>

<p class ='para'>This is (color)</p>
<!-- if color1 is clicked in the menu then the <body> background will be changed to color1 and the innerHTML will also be changed to color1. The background color and targeted text changes according to the menu item clicked ->
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is the actual question? "Looking for inspiration" is too vague for SO's Q&A format. Is the question the title? "Would like a single function/event handler to do the same thing"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with that code, but basically: Yes, you can use a single event handler to handle all four links. The process is called "event delegation" — delegating the handling of the event to some ancestor element. In this case, the `ul` makes a good place to put a `click` handler. `click` events "bubble" from the target element (the `li`) to its parent, then *its* parent, etc., so we can handle a click on any `li` in the `ul` by handling it on the `ul`.

See comments:

```js
// Handle click on the `ul.nav`:
document.querySelector(".nav").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // `event.target` is the element the event was targeted at (the `li`
    // element). We can use the `closest` method to find the first element
    // starting with that one and then working through its parent, parent's
    // parent, etc., until we find one that matches the selector. The
    // selector looks for an element that has a `data-color` attribute.
    const li = event.target.closest("[data-color]");
    // If we found one and it's within the element we hooked `click` on
    // (the `ul`), we handle the click
    if (li && this.contains(li)) {
        // Get the color from the attribute
        const color = li.getAttribute("data-color");
        // Assign it to the body
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
        // Show the color name in the `span`
        document.querySelector(".color").textContent = color;
    }
});
```

```css
li[data-color] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <!-- I've removed the classes and set a data-* attribute with the color to set -->
    <!-- I've also removed the `a` elements. Because they're links, clicking follows them -->
    <li data-color="#E0E0E0">color1</li>
    <li data-color="#D0D0D0">color2</li>
    <li data-color="#C0C0C0">color3</li>
    <li data-color="#B0B0B0">color4</li>
</ul>

<!-- Note that I've changed the opening angle bracket in the `p` tag below to its
     character reference form (&lt;) so it's not handled as a paragraph -->
<h2>The text in the &lt;p> tag below changes according to clicked link in the menu</h2>

<!-- I've added a span with a class so we can set the color name -->
<p class="para">This is <span class="color">(no color yet)</span></p>
```

More

- [Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
- [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

If you wanted to do it with the `a` elements (so we get default tabbing and "activation" on various user gestures, like pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>), we can do much the same thing just with a `event.preventDefault()` call to tell the browser not to follow the `href` of the `a`. When doing that, it's usually best to have the `href` indicate to the user what it's going to do, so we can use that rather than a `data-*` attribute:

```js
// The prefix used on `a` element `href`s:
const prefix = "#set-color-";

// Handle click on the `ul.nav`:
document.querySelector(".nav").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // `event.target` is the element the event was targeted at (the `li`
    // element). We can use the `closest` method to find the first element
    // starting with that one and then working through its parent, parent's
    // parent, etc., until we find one that matches the selector. The
    // selector looks for an `a` element whose `href` *starts with* the
    // text `set-color-`
    const anchor = event.target.closest(`a[href^="${prefix}"]`);
    // If we found one and it's within the element we hooked `click` on
    // (the `ul`), we handle the click
    if (anchor && this.contains(anchor)) {
        // Get the color from the `href` by grabbing the part after the
        // prefix
        const color = anchor.getAttribute("href").substring(prefix.length);
        // Assign it to the body
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
        // Show the color name in the `span`
        document.querySelector(".color").textContent = color;
        // Prevent the default of following the anchor
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```css
li[data-color] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <!-- I've removed the classes and set a data-* attribute with the color to set -->
    <!-- I've also removed the `a` elements. Because they're links, clicking follows them -->
    <li><a href="#set-color-#E0E0E0">color1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#set-color-#D0D0D0">color2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#set-color-#C0C0C0">color3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#set-color-#B0B0B0">color4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Note that I've changed the opening angle bracket in the `p` tag below to its
     character reference form (&lt;) so it's not handled as a paragraph -->
<h2>The text in the &lt;p> tag below changes according to clicked link in the menu</h2>

<!-- I've added a span with a class so we can set the color name -->
<p class="para">This is <span class="color">(no color yet)</span></p>
```